# Matplotlib, I'm making a 2d histogram and I want to a triangular axes extension similar to what is done with colorbars

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Using MATPLOTLIB.PYPLOT I am making a 2d histogram where I want to limit my view to a certain range of y-values but at the same time I want to cluster all values below a certain number at the bottom of the y-axis. What i'm thinking of is similar to how you can make a colorbar have triangular extensions and anything within those extensions is plotted to certain conditions. What I want to do is similar except it involves the y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this that I can think of is to filter your data before calling the histogram. Here is an example using `np.where` to filter the y data.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(17)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some random normal data
N = 100000
x = np.random.normal(-2, 3, N) 
y = np.random.normal(3, 6, N) 

# use np.where to set all y values less than -10 to -10
y = np.where(y < -10, -10, y)

# now apply histogram2d
xbins = np.linspace(-10, 10, 101)
ybins = np.linspace(-10, 10, 101)

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=(xbins, ybins))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xedges, yedges)

# plot data with pcolormesh
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

img = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, H)

ax.set_xlim(xedges.min(), xedges.max())
ax.set_ylim(yedges.min(), yedges.max())

plt.colorbar(img)
```

You can see the distribution of all the thresholded values on the bottom of the y axis.

[image]